# c++ dynamically declared array fails to work

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, theory, heap-memory

I am trying to read the file's data into a dynamically declared array, using `double *data = new double[14141414]()` declaration.  Note, it is rather a large file; hence large size of an array.

The problem is I can not put all the data into an array as somewhere around index=14000000 the execution would just stop.
The code compiles just fine (no errors).  I did debug and the `new` returns an address, not 0 or NULL.  So looks like there is no problem with memory allocation (ie running out of memory). I even echo-ed the file to screen without array assignment just to see that I am able to read through the file well.  All looks good.

Yet, the moment I start putting data into an array, the program would just stop closer to the end but at random locations, Sometime it would be 14000000 sometimes the index would be a little bit more and sometimes a little bit less.  There were couple times when the program ran well.

Does  anybody know what is going on?  I suspect the the computer running out of physical memory and hence this behavior of the program.  But if this is so, then why does `new` operator return an address?  Should it return 0 or NULL if memory allocate fails?

Thanks!!

UPDATE:  per #Jonathan Potter's request I am including the code here.  Thanks!!  Really good idea!!

```
void importData(){

int totalLineCount = 14141414;

double *height = new (nothrow) double[totalLineCount]();
int *weight = new (nothrow) int[totalLineCount]();
double *pulse = new (nothrow) double[totalLineCount]();
string *dateTime = new (nothrow) string[totalLineCount];
int *year = new (nothrow) int[totalLineCount]();
int *month = new (nothrow) int[totalLineCount]();
int *day = new (nothrow) int[totalLineCount]();

fstream dataFile(file.location.c_str(), ios::in);
for (int i = 0; i < totalLineCount; i++) {      
  dataFile >> weight[i] 
      >> height[i] 
      >> pulse[i]
      >> year[i] 
      >> dateTime[i]; 
  } //for
dataFile.close();

delete height;
delete weight;
delete pulse;
delete dateTime;
delete year;
delete month;
delete day;

}//function end
```

Comment: Modern computers should have no trouble with an array of 14 million doubles. Show your code.

Comment: Why cant you use a `std::vector`? It will make your life much easier ...

Comment: can it be a file reading problem?

Comment: #Jonathan Potter and #barak manos, thanks for a request.  Code is included in the original post now.

Comment: Maybe the file does not have 14141414 lines.

Comment: Thanks, #Tim3880, I do not think so it is a file reading problem.  I am able to read and immediately output the ALL of the file contents without the assignment to arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, #Ben.  I was thinking about that too.  But I thought working with raw arrays might be speed efficient compared to vectors.  Vectors are on my list to try if nothing else works out.

Comment: yes, I was thinking the same things too,   #drescherjm.  I counted using wc -l file.txt (linux) and then another way.  Both seemed to produce the same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

save yourself loads of trouble, use a `vector`

```
std::vector<double> data;
data.reserve(SIZE_OF_ARRAY); // not totally required, but will speed up filling the values
```

vector will give you better debug messages and you won't have to deal with memory yourself.

Comment: Thanks, #twentylemon.  But can vectors sustain large sizes?   I was somehow was thinking that for large data sets using dynamically declared arrays was better.  But maybe not, right?

Comment: vector is an array in the backend. The `reserve` call makes sure the array is big enough to hold all your data so each insertion doesn't require copying the array into a bigger one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use vector. this however does not answer my original question about why `new` operator might not work in the above example.

Comment: `new` should have worked, really. I'm not sure why it didn't. I'm not sure what the `()` does after each; that could be the issue. `new T[length]` is the normal syntax you'd see.

Comment: I believe `()` initialize everything to zero in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your "new" memory allocation block need to correct as follows, there is no need of `()` at end of each line.

```
double *height = new (nothrow) double[totalLineCount];
int *weight = new (nothrow) int[totalLineCount];
double *pulse = new (nothrow) double[totalLineCount];
string *dateTime = new (nothrow) string[totalLineCount];
int *year = new (nothrow) int[totalLineCount];
int *month = new (nothrow) int[totalLineCount];
int *day = new (nothrow) int[totalLineCount];
```

And you "delete" block need to correct as follows:

```
delete [] height;
delete []weight[];
delete []pulse;
delete []dateTime;
delete []year;
delete []month;
delete []day;
```

I think improper delete operation may be reason for your failure. You allocated memory for arrays but de-allocated by using pointer syntax of  delete instead using array syntax.

And another probability for the issue may be lack of physical memory, because as per code you are allocating a lot of memory, not only a double array as you mentioned earlier in question. There is an array of std::string and a few more.

To avoid all memory allocation and de-allocation hurdles better you can go for `std::vector` in place of array. In one of your comments you raised concern of performance benefit by comparing array and std::vector. If you are using compiler optimizations , (if in case of gcc `-O2`) `std::vector`  will be at par with array unless you may make some serious mistake in your implementation.

Comment: #Steephen, thanks so much for a suggestion.  I will update my code and try again.  But why would delete affect the data assignments if the program stops before for-loop completes?

Comment: @JavaFan I am not sure, how you confirmed program aborted within for loop?  Another possible chance system allocation went out of memory, I missed to add it in my answer, because you are allocating a lot of memory not only a double array.

Comment: Thanks, #Steephen.  The reason why I know it's inside the loop is I cout data on every iteration.  And after so many iterations before exiting the loop, the program just stops.

Comment: @JavaFan std::cout is a stream and using buffer, so it may not be exact as you observe.